# Selecting from XML field where XML field = X

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

So I am trying to select each record out of a SQL Server table that has a `<FIELD>` equal to `Payment method` but I want the value of the `<NEWVALUE>`. I can't seem to get anything even close to what I want. Any ideas?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c0a0/1/0

(Fiddle Contents)

```
create table T1(ID int identity(1, 1), XMLFIELD xml)
insert into T1(XMLFIELD) values('<ITEMS>
  <ITEM>
    <PROCESS>True</PROCESS>
    <FIELD>Amount</FIELD>
    <NEWVALUE>100</NEWVALUE>
    <ACTION>0</ACTION>
    <FIELDKEY>AMOUNT</FIELDKEY>
    <DATATYPE>4</DATATYPE>
  </ITEM>  
  <ITEM>
    <PROCESS>True</PROCESS>
    <FIELD>Payment method</FIELD>
    <NEWVALUE>Credit card</NEWVALUE>
    <ACTION>0</ACTION>
    <FIELDKEY>PAYMENTMETHODCODE</FIELDKEY>
    <DATATYPE>1</DATATYPE>
  </ITEM>  
</ITEMS>')
insert into T1(XMLFIELD) values('<ITEMS>
  <ITEM>
    <PROCESS>True</PROCESS>
    <FIELD>Amount</FIELD>
    <NEWVALUE>25</NEWVALUE>
    <ACTION>0</ACTION>
    <FIELDKEY>AMOUNT</FIELDKEY>
    <DATATYPE>4</DATATYPE>
  </ITEM>  
  <ITEM>
    <PROCESS>True</PROCESS>
    <FIELD>Payment method</FIELD>
    <NEWVALUE>Debit</NEWVALUE>
    <ACTION>0</ACTION>
    <FIELDKEY>PAYMENTMETHODCODE</FIELDKEY>
    <DATATYPE>2</DATATYPE>
  </ITEM>  
</ITEMS>')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    NewValue = XItem.value('(NEWVALUE)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    T1
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlField.nodes('/ITEMS/ITEM') as XTbl(XItem)
WHERE
    XItem.exist('FIELD[.="Payment method"]') = 1
```